# Passing wrong argument for TensorFlow method

Tags: image, tensorflow, classification

I am trying to classify two objects. I would like to get Accuracy and Cross Entropy from the `evaluate.py` script.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```py
evaluate.py (by tensorflow for poets)
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os

import sys
import argparse

import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
import tensorflow as tf

import scripts.retrain as retrain
from scripts.count_ops import load_graph


def evaluate_graph(graph_file_name):
    with load_graph(graph_file_name).as_default() as graph:
    ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, [None, 5], name='GroundTruthInput')

    image_buffer_input = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    final_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
    accuracy, _ = retrain.add_evaluation_step(final_tensor, ground_truth_input)

    logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name("final_training_ops/Wx_plus_b/add:0")
    xent = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=ground_truth_input,
        logits=logits))

#image_dir = 'tf_files/flower_photos'
image_dir = 'tf_files/test_images'
testing_percentage = 10
validation_percentage = 10
validation_batch_size = 100
category = 'testing'

image_lists = retrain.create_image_lists(
    image_dir, testing_percentage,
    validation_percentage)
class_count = len(image_lists.keys())

ground_truths = []
filenames = []

for label_index, label_name in enumerate(image_lists.keys()):
    for image_index, image_name in enumerate(image_lists[label_name][category]):
        image_name = retrain.get_image_path(
            image_lists, label_name, image_index, image_dir, category)
        ground_truth = np.zeros([1, class_count], dtype=np.float32)
        ground_truth[0, label_index] = 1.0
        ground_truths.append(ground_truth)
        filenames.append(image_name)

accuracies = []
xents = []
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    for filename, ground_truth in zip(filenames, ground_truths):
        image = Image.open(filename).resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)[None, ...]
        image = (image - 128) / 128.0

        feed_dict = {
            image_buffer_input: image,
            ground_truth_input: ground_truth}

        eval_accuracy, eval_xent = sess.run([accuracy, xent], feed_dict)

        accuracies.append(eval_accuracy)
        xents.append(eval_xent)

return np.mean(accuracies), np.mean(xents)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
    accuracy, xent = evaluate_graph(*sys.argv[1:])
    print('Accuracy: %g' % accuracy)
    print('Cross Entropy: %g' % xent)
```

However when I run the above script for prediction I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 224, 224) for Tensor
>   u'input:0', which has shape '(1, 224, 224, 3)'

How can I solve this error?

Comment: you are trying to feed in the greyscale image (1 channel) to the input which requires RGB (3 channels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are feeding grayscale images into input placeholder. Grayscale images have only 1 channel, hence the shape `(224, 224, )` (dimension of size 1 is omitted), while pretrained network you are trying requires RGB images with 3 channels and shape `(224, 224, 3)`

If your images are actualy RGB, you might have an error here:

```py
image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)[None, ...]
```

this indexing: `[None, ...]` does not seem necessary.

If your images are actually grayscale, you may convert them into RGB format using [`PIL.convert()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) (one channel will be repeated 3 times):

```py
image = image.convert("RGB")
```

Although with channel duplication running 3-channel CNN is inefficient (computation is performed for the same data 3 times) and likely will perform worse than with colored images, this should run the script and will get you on track quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used grayscale images.

Comment: @Jun I addeed the information on how to "fake" RGB images.